# Unable to create schema of table in mongo database

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a database in `mongodb`. I have this sample JSON format

```
{
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Doe",
    memberships: ["mem1", "mem2"],
    address: {
        street: "4 main st",
        city: "Boston"
    },
    contacts: [
        {
            name: "Brad",
            relationship: "friend"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created a database and collection "user". I want to define a schema of this collection as like above JSON.

I am using mongodb compass tool https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass to create database, collection, schema, managing etc, I am applying this JSON in input box which is left of apply button, so on clicking on apply button it does not  create a schema.

Does anyone know what is the way to create a schema of collection using this tool ?

[image]

Comment: MongoDB is a "schemaless" database. You do not define properties and types for "tables" in the way you do for a SQL based database. Modern versions allow for creation of rudimentary "validation" rules, but that is as far as it goes. So the "database" is not responsible fro schema. Instead this task is delegated to your "client" code. What you want is an ORM/ODM product, which allows classing of objects for data access that represents a "schema". Sold separately (actually free, but not part of the product) to MongoDB. Search for one https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+ORM

Comment: Is there any tool to import a JSON document in a specific collection ? @Neil Lunn

Comment: Yes. But that is not the question you asked here. The format here is Q&A which means you ask a question and get an answer to **that** question. If you have a new question then [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Or alternately do a little searching or indeed [read the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/). At your current reputation score and number of participation badges present, then no-one should really need to tell you this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that `mongodb` is schema less database. You can insert any type of document in a single collection, but you should avoid to insert complete application data in a single collection.

You should create multiple collection to see fast execution of find queries.

[image]